# Run bash script as a sudo user with some other computations

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have some other piece of bash script calling some external other scripts and running as a `sudo` user. Below is an example which can be used as a sample to reproduce my problem.

```
#!/bin/bash
databaseName=${1}
tableNames=${2}
IFS=','
read -r -a tableNamesArray <<< "${tableNames}"
#sudo su <<WRAPPER
echo "Tables inside ${databaseName} are ::: ${tableNamesArray[@]}"
echo "-- SQL FILE  --" > ${databaseName}_schema.hql
echo "$tableNames"
echo "${tableNamesArray[@]}"
for eachTable in "${tableNamesArray[@]}"
  do
    echo "$eachTable"
    echo "MY_QUERY $databaseName.$eachTable;" >> ${databaseName}_schema.hql
  done
#WRAPPER
```

This script is working fine. I want `mydb_schema.hql` with some records of SQL script. Assume I am calling this above as `./sample.sh db table1,table2` to get a SQL file with below queries-

```
-- SQL FILE  --
MY_QUERY db.table1;
MY_QUERY db.table2;
```

Above is working fine and getting all as per my need.
Here is my problem-

```
#!/bin/bash
databaseName=${1}
tableNames=${2}
IFS=','
read -r -a tableNamesArray <<< "${tableNames}"
sudo su <<WRAPPER
#..Other scripts that I need to call as sudo..
echo "Tables inside ${databaseName} are ::: ${tableNamesArray[@]}"
echo "-- SQL FILE  --" > ${databaseName}_schema.hql
echo "$tableNames"
echo "${tableNamesArray[@]}"
for eachTable in "${tableNamesArray[@]}"
  do
    echo "$eachTable"
    echo "MY_QUERY $databaseName.$eachTable;" >> ${databaseName}_schema.hql
  done
WRAPPER
```

I have used like this and I am able to call other scripts as a `sudo` user in between code. This `WRAPPER`is working fine to call other scripts as a `sudo` user but not able to call `for` loop inside the `WRAPPER`. Not sure what problem is for me? Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "*as a sudo user*"?

Comment: As a `root` user in other words.@melpomene

Comment: Why just not run the script as `sudo sample.sh table1, table 2....`?

Comment: Well, I want to become root first and then run because of some other scripts. Not sure @kabanus whatever you are saying would work?

Comment: Running `sudo sample.sh ....` will make everything inside be run with `root` permissions. If this is not the external most script, run the external most script with `sudo`.

Comment: You'll need to put a `./` in front of the script name unless it's on the `PATH`.